# How to do weight initialization by Xavier rule in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

TF 2.0 happened to get rid of `contrib` library. Therefore, all the goodies like `tf.contrib.conv2d` or `tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer` are gone. That said, what do you think would be the best way to do Xavier initialization in TF2.0 without using Keras (or initializing with some numpy hack)?

Namely, I am sticking to `tf.nn.conv2d` and for that function I am the one providing the weights:

```
filters = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 3, 32, 64]))
??? # something should happen hear, i guess
net = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filters)
```

**Note:** Just in case you are using the first version of TF you can just go with:

```
filters = tf.get_variable("w", shape=[3,3, 32, 64],
           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) 
# no tf.contrib in 2.0, no tf.get_variable in 2.0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.0 you have a package `tf.initializer` with all the Keras-like initializers you need.

The Xavier initializer is the same as the Glorot Uniform initializer. Thus, to create a `(3,3)` variable with values sampled from that initializer you can just:

```
shape = (3,3)
initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()
var = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=shape))
```

Comment: Hi~May I ask a question? I can't find parameter ```uniform=False``` in ```tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()``` . What should I do if I want to replace ```tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `glorot uniform initializer` which is the same as `xavier initializer`.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer

Also here is an example to prove that they are the same:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(42)
xavier_var = tf.get_variable("w_xavier", shape=[3, 3], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(xavier_var))
# [[ 0.27579927 -0.6790426  -0.6128938 ]
#  [-0.49439836 -0.36137486 -0.7235348 ]
#  [-0.23143482 -0.3394227  -0.34756017]]
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(42)
glorot_var = tf.get_variable("w_glorot", shape=[3, 3], initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(glorot_var))
# [[ 0.27579927 -0.6790426  -0.6128938 ]
#  [-0.49439836 -0.36137486 -0.7235348 ]
#  [-0.23143482 -0.3394227  -0.34756017]]
```

In addition, if you want to the `glorot uniform initializer` with `tf.Variable` you can do:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(42)
normal_var = tf.Variable(tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()((3, 3)))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(normal_var))
# [[ 0.27579927 -0.6790426  -0.6128938 ]
#  [-0.49439836 -0.36137486 -0.7235348 ]
#  [-0.23143482 -0.3394227  -0.34756017]]
```

Comment: good point, definitely a step in the right direction. Yet, in TF2.0 glorot initializer resides in tf.initializers.glorot_uniform (and can be viewed here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py). It seems to be some kind of Keras thing, though. tf.get_variable is also no longer a thing in TF2.0

Comment: See my update, this should solve the issue you are encountering.

Comment: What does ```shape = (3,3)``` stands for? Shape of what?

Answer (score 1):

You can change, from Tensorflow v1:

```
initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
```

to Tensorflow v2:

```
initializer=tf.initializers.glorot_uniform()
```

Answer (score 1):

from Tensorflow v1:

```
initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)
```

to Tensorflow v2:

```
initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()
```

[Documentation for `GlorotNormal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotNormal)

I concluded this answer according to the description in Tensorflow Guide.