# change tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer() to 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

how can I change

```
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
```

to tf version >= 2.0.0 ??

all codes:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[self.input_size, h_size],
                             initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the TF2 replacement for `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` is  `tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal`(Xavier and Glorot are 2 names for the same initializer algorithm, referring to [one researcher named Xavier Glorot](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=_WnkXlkAAAAJ&hl=en)) [documentation link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotNormal).

if dtype is important for some compatibility reasons - use `tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.glorot_normal`

Answer (score 4):

Just to slightly clarify [@poe-dator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10396469/poe-dator) answer's:
Using TF slim's `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` without any parameters, returns uniformly distributed weights ([`uniform=True` set by default](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim/blob/master/tf_slim/layers/initializers.py#L32)).

So basically, the mapping between TF Slim and Keras works as follows:

- `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` should be replaced by
  `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()`
- `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)` should be replaced by
  `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()`

This difference is also noted in another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322754/how-to-do-weight-initialization-by-xavier-rule-in-tensorflow-2-0), so kudos to the posters there.