# Code written on tensorflow 1.7 has wildly different performance in tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, multilabel-classification

A few years ago I created a NN to analyze an accelerometer signal for my experiments. I recently got a new computer and after having installed tflow and all the appropriate drivers, my code no longer works (even after the version 2 converter). In version 1, my model was 97% accurate on predicting the class on my test set. On tensorflow 2, on the same data, my model performance is 75%. I have tried everything I can think of to no avail and am losing it because my thesis needs to be finished soon. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
pred=tf.placeholder("float",)

initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

##XAVIER INITIALIZATION##
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(initializer([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'h3': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3])),
    'weight_out': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_3, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(initializer([n_hidden_3])),
    'bias_out': tf.Variable(initializer([n_classes]))
}

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']))
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2']))
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3']))
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['weight_out']) + biases['bias_out']
    return out_layer

logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)
'''
# Define loss and optimizer
#loss_opo no weights
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=Y))
'''

###############################################################
#weighted_loss
loss_weights=tf.constant(([[0.8, 1.2, 1.1, 1.05, 1.1]]))
loss_op=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits,targets=Y,pos_weight=loss_weights))

################################################################

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
optimizer_SGD=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate) 
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)


#######################################
## EVALUATE MODEL
# evaluates accuracy of softmax of logit output
#
pred=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
#
## Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
```

I have tried everything

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/64255154/? If you update it and it doesn't work. Please feel free to update your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me! So i tried the following:
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) -> tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) and it is still having strange performance issues. Perhaps the most perplexing issue is that the model is able to achieve high accuracy on both the train/validation set...

Comment: Before you post it in a comment, please [edit] the question to update it. Commenting messes up the formatting. I'll be following the question for a while. But according to that link I posted, it looks like one of the issues may be that `xavier_initializer` needs to be updated?