# Tensorflow : TypeError: convolution2d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kernel_initializer'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to code an auto-encoder in **TensorFlow (v 1.14.0)** . I want to set the `kernel_initializer` as **Xavier initialization**. However,
when I call the `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d()` in the code as :

```
Conv = layers.conv2d(
inputs=X, 
num_outputs=64, 
kernel_size=5, 
stride=[2,1],
activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
)
```

I am getting the following error in the argument `kernel_initializer` :

```
File "/data/my_new_env37/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 182, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
TypeError: convolution2d() got an unexpected keyword argument kernel_initializer
```

The code works fine without the `kernel_initializer` argument.
What does this error mean ? How do I resolve it ?

Comment: Try using 'tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()' instead of 'tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()' they work same. You can visit [Weight Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322754/how-to-do-weight-initialization-by-xavier-rule-in-tensorflow-2-0) for reference

Comment: @Shag I am using TensorFlow v1.14.0 . I tried your solution but that seems to work for TensorFlow v2 and above . The issue I am facing is that "kernel_initializer" is being shown as an unexpected keyword argument, which ideally shouldn't be happening. How do I resolve the issue for tf 1.14.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I am not used to Tensorflow v1.14.0, but what I can see from the documentation is that the `kernel_initializer` keyword is not accepted by the api `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d`, here is the link of the API [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.14/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d.md).

But still you can use other API for the `conv2d` that is `tf.layers.Conv2D`, here is the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.14/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2D.md) for the same. This API provides the option to provide `kernel_initializer`.

As I am not that used to Tensorflow v1.14.0, so I will not be able to provide what is the actual difference between these two API's. But I will give this API a try.